# How can I set connect/write/read timeout on HttpClient

Tags: java, reactor-netty

I need to write a library works for [spring-boot-2.1.6](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html) which uses [reactor-netty:0.8.9.RELEASE](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.projectreactor.netty/reactor-netty/0.8.9.RELEASE/index.html).

How can I set connect/write/read timeout on an instance of [HttpClient](https://javadoc.io/static/io.projectreactor.netty/reactor-netty/0.8.21.RELEASE/reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient.html) and/or on an instance of [TcpClient](https://javadoc.io/static/io.projectreactor.netty/reactor-netty/0.8.21.RELEASE/index.html?reactor/netty/tcp/TcpClient.html)?

I just found that I can set a connection timeout like this.

```java
final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
        .tcpConfiguration(tc -> {
            Optional.ofNullable(getConnectTimeout())
                    .map(Duration::toMillis)
                    .map(Math::toIntExact)
                    .ifPresent(ct -> {
                        tc.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, ct);
                    });
            return tc;
        });
```

Is that right? And how can I set write/read time out?

Comment: `ChannelOption.SO_TIMEOUT` appears to be a read timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set read/write timeout like this:

```java
import io.netty.channel.Channel;
import io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler;
import io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;
import reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TimeoutSetting {

    private HttpClient createHttpClient(Duration connectTimeout, Duration readTimeout, Duration writeTimeout) {
        return HttpClient.create()
                .tcpConfiguration(tcpClient -> tcpClient
                        .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, Math.toIntExact(connectTimeout.toMillis()))
                        .doOnConnected(connection -> {
                            connection.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(Math.toIntExact(readTimeout.toMillis()), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                            connection.addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(Math.toIntExact(writeTimeout.toMillis()), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                        }));
    }

}
```

Use it like this:

```java
    HttpClient httpClient = createHttpClient(
        Duration.ofSeconds(10), // Connect timeout
        Duration.ofSeconds(30), // Read timeout
        Duration.ofSeconds(20)  // Write timeout
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need a config class that encapsulates the creation of the `HTTPClient` with timeouts:

```java
public class HttpClientConfiguration {
  public HttpClient createHttpClient() {
    final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().tcpConfiguration(tc -> {
      // set connection timeout
      Optional.ofNullable(getConnectTimeout())
          .map(Duration::toMillis)
          .map(Math::toIntExact)
          .ifPresent(ct -> tc.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, ct));

      // add r/w timeout handlers
      tc.doOnConnected(conn -> {
        Optional.ofNullable(getReadTimeout())
            .map(Duration::getSeconds)
            .map(sec -> new ReadTimeoutHandler(sec, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .ifPresent(conn::addHandlerLast);

        Optional.ofNullable(getWriteTimeout())
            .map(Duration::getSeconds)
            .map(sec -> new WriteTimeoutHandler(sec, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .ifPresent(conn::addHandlerLast);
      });

      return tc;
    });

    return httpClient;
  }

  // example timeout retrieval
  private Duration getConnectTimeout() {
    return Duration.ofSeconds(10);
  }
  private Duration getReadTimeout() {
    return Duration.ofSeconds(5);
  }
  private Duration getWriteTimeout() {
    return Duration.ofSeconds(5);
  }
}
```

with this `HTTPClient`, you can now make a service to make HTTP calls:

```java
@Service
public class ExternalApiService {
  private final HttpClient httpClient;

  public ExternalApiService(HttpClientConfiguration httpClientConfiguration) {
    this.httpClient = httpClientConfiguration.createHttpClient();
  }

  public Mono<String> fetchExternalData(String url) {
    return this.httpClient.get().uri(url).responseSingle(
        (response, byteBufMono) -> byteBufMono.asString());
  }
}
```

now you can use `ExternalApiService` in controllers to get external data:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ExternalApiController {
  private final ExternalApiService externalApiService;

  public ExternalApiController(ExternalApiService externalApiService) {
    this.externalApiService = externalApiService;
  }

  @GetMapping("/fetch-data")
  public Mono<String> fetchData(@RequestParam String url) {
    return externalApiService.fetchExternalData(url);
  }
}
```